# Modify markers size on hover Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, leaflet

I have some markers that I load it from a database, but the problem is when I hover on a marker I should change the icon, I can successfully do this, but if I hover on another marker, the first clicked marker is having the icon changed and the on that I hovered remained the same.

Any ideas what can I do?

```js
function addScoala1() {
  var scoala = JSON.parse('<?php echo json_encode($scoala) ?>');
  for (var i = 0; i < scoala.length; i++) {
    var greenIcon = new L.Icon({
      iconUrl: 'https://static1.squarespace.com/static/540ed918e4b0daae9995d1d7/54ecab60e4b0feaa477dac5a/54ecab79e4b0c686e92227d7/1424796549381/university.png',
      shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png',
      iconSize: [35, 40],
      iconAnchor: [12, 41],
      popupAnchor: [1, -34],
      shadowSize: [10, 10]
    });
    var marker = L.marker([scoala[i]['latitudine'], scoala[i]['longitudine']], {
      icon: greenIcon
    }).addTo(groupA);
    marker.bindPopup("<b>" + scoala[i]['scoala'] + "</b><br>Detalii:" + scoala[i]['detalii'] + "<br />Telefon: " + scoala[i]['telefon']);
    L.Icon.Big = L.Icon.extend({
      options: {
        iconSize: new L.Point(44, 61),
        iconUrl: 'https://static1.squarespace.com/static/540ed918e4b0daae9995d1d7/54ecab60e4b0feaa477dac5a/54ecab79e4b0c686e92227d7/1424796549381/university.png',
        shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png'
      }
    });

    var bigIcon = new L.Icon.Big();
    marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
      this.openPopup();
      marker.setIcon(bigIcon);
    });
    marker.on('mouseout', function(e) {
      this.closePopup();
      marker.setIcon(greenIcon);
    });
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you create a **working** [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) for this? It will much easier for us to help you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue here is related to scope and async events.

```
marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
  this.openPopup();
  marker.setIcon(bigIcon);//marker object is overwritten in the for loop each time
});
```

You can use instead

```
e.target.setIcon(bigIcon);
```

Same for `mouseout`

Otherwise you can do some wrapping with an [immediatly invoked function](http://tech.myemma.com/iifes-javascript-control-variable-scope/) to preserve scope, as so:

```
function(marker){
    marker.on('mouseover', function(e) {
      this.openPopup();
      marker.setIcon(bigIcon);
    });
}(marker)
```

Comment: Cool.
Also added a solution with immediatly invoked function

Comment: Thank u very much, I'll use it. Also, can you help me with some polygon editing? I want to change the color of the polygon when I edit it, can I do this?

Comment: Just use css. I saw this class '.leaflet-interactive' has the blue.
You can overwrite by several methods of css, the most brutish and effective one is to use !important

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153610/discussion-between-robinson-chera-and-skarlinski).

Comment: @RobinsonChera color of what are you want to change?

Comment: @MoshFeu the color of the polygon that I draw from database, I just created a topic